# Select all from db with likes and without likes

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

How to select all posts in the database that have likes. And i also want all posts without likes to be listed in the same SQL-Query. The likes are stored in a table and the every table is conncted to a post with a foreign key

```
SELECT likes.*, posts. * , profile . *, credentials.username, posts.session_sessionid as sSession 
FROM likes, posts, follows, profile, credentials 
WHERE follows.users = posts.userId 
AND profile.userId= follows.users 
AND profile.userId = credentials.profle_userId 
AND posts.session_sessionId IS NOT NULL 
AND likes.idposts = posts.idposts ORDER BY posts.date DESC`
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an `outer join` instead.  And if you want to add the `like count` to the result, one option is to use another subquery to get the `count`:

```
SELECT likes.*, t.likecount, posts.* ,profile.*, credentials.username, 
       posts.session_sessionid as sSession 
FROM posts 
    join follows on follows.users = posts.userId 
    join profile on profile.userId= follows.users 
    join credentials on profile.userId = credentials.profle_userId
    left join likes on likes.idposts = posts.idposts
    left join (
        select idposts, count(*) likecount
        from likes 
        group by idposts
    ) t on t.idposts = posts.idposts
WHERE posts.session_sessionId IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY posts.date DESC`
```

In general I wouldn't recommend using commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Is there any way where i make the Query to count the rows in the table `likes`? I tried `count(likes.*)` but Im getting an error.

Comment: @TheZozoOwner -- just add another `outer join` using a subquery to `count` the likes per post.  Edited to show you an example.